# No power to bike

Tags: ignition

I have a 125cc scooter, n you turn the key and there’s no movement on the dash and no lights, the bike won’t start at all. It’s fairly new, I’ve checked the fuses and they’re all connect and in perfect condition, I have fuel and oil, it’s not on the stand when starting, n the kill switch isn’t in use when starting.  Any ideas??

Comment: Have you checked the battery voltage?

Comment: Give it a jump start from another bike, or tuned off car(if the car is on you might wreck havok on the bike electrical system)